# Oracle Update statement not working correctly

Tags: sql, oracle, date, sql-update

I want to consider for every combination of field value `OID` and `EXID` take the min `LATEST_MODIFICATION_DATE` and update the same in `FIRST_INSERTION_DATE`.

I have lot of redundant rows with the combination of field value `OID` and `EXID`. But it should not be problem to set the min `LATEST_MODIFICATION_DATE` date for all those values.

I tried the below query but its not working correctly:

```
update O_TEST t
set FIRST_INSERTION_DATE = (select min (LATEST_MODIFICATION_DATE) from O_TEST)
where rowid < (
  select max(rowid)
  from OBS_ORDER_ID_MAPPING_TEST t2
  where t.EXID = t2.EXID
    and t.OID = t2.OID
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a correlated subquery for the `set`:

```
update O_TEST t
    set FIRST_INSERTION_DATE = (select min(t2.LATEST_MODIFICATION_DATE)
                                from O_TEST t2
                                where t2.EXID = t.EXID and t2.OID = t.OID
                               )
    where LATEST_MODIFICATION_DATE <> (select min(t2.LATEST_MODIFICATION_DATE)
                                       from O_TEST t2
                                       where (t2.EXID = t.EXID or t2.EXID is null and t.EXID is null) and
                                             t2.OID = t.OID
                                      );
```

To handle `NULL` values, you need to take those into account in the correlated subqueries:

```
update O_TEST t
    set FIRST_INSERTION_DATE = (select min(t2.LATEST_MODIFICATION_DATE)
                                from O_TEST t2
                                where t2.EXID = t.EXID and
```

t2.OID = t.OID
)
where LATEST_MODIFICATION_DATE <> (select min(t2.LATEST_MODIFICATION_DATE)
from O_TEST t2
where (t2.EXID = t.EXID or t2.EXID is null and t.EXID is null) and
t2.OID = t.OID
);

From your comment `OID` is not `NULL`, but if so, you can use similar logic for that as well.

Comment: it works fine but i also have EXID which are null for OID, in this case the date has not been updated

Comment: how de we consider those combination of values as well ?